# cannot disable UIButton

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have UIView > UIView > Custom UIButton with a simple image.
It is a refresh button that I need to hide while I am downloading and processing the xml file, so the user is not able to trigger the refresh multiple times.
This is the code I use to do that:

self.myRefreshButton.enabled = NO;
self.myRefreshButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[self.myRefreshButton removeFromSuperview];

Unfortunately, it does not work. Although the button is removed, I am able to touch and trigger the button.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you performing this code on a different thread (or in the background)?

Comment: last time i had this problem, it was because i had forgotten to set the outlet in IB.

Comment: Same thread. The main thread. After the button is touched, the action triggers, and that is where I try to disable the button. It will be enabled after all the work is done in a separate thread, which will notify the main thread of that fact. The problem is that after disabling I am still able to touch and trigger the action.

Comment: The IB outlet for the myRefreshButton is set correctly. Just in case I removed and re-added it with no luck.

Comment: Looks like the UI is not updating for some reason. It takes a couple of seconds after I re-enable the button for the UI to show me that the button is there. The touch is registered though, that is why the action is triggered. Now I am really lost :)) [self.myRefreshButton setNeedsDisplay]; makes no difference. I am not overriding drawRect.

Comment: Evan, I think you might have a good point that I overlooked. The background work is done by parseQueue = [NSOperationQueue new]; at some point the operation invokes a method on the main thread where the refreshButton is set to YES. (so it is not done by using notifications, sorry for the confusion) and then the control flow continues in the background thread :) something might not be right here. In the background thread the block of code that invoked the method in the main thread is run through the end, and then a new debugger window is popped up "asm objc_msgSend" that I am not familiar with.

Comment: The dealloc is called on the background thread instance, but the button does not show at the same time, so the UI I guess is not updated at the same moment.

Comment: Finally, got it! the problem was that I invoked a method from the background threat on the main thread: [self.myMain doILoadStaticContent]; The solution was to invoke the following in the background thread [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doILoadStaticContent) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; and then define a method in the background thread - (void) doILoadStaticContent {[self.myMain doILoadStaticContent];} that invokes the same named method in the main thread. thanks Evan for the idea. how do I give you credit for it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you forgot to link the button the your myRefreshButton property in Interface Builder. Check your connections there.

Comment: I checked, deleted and then re-added. I guess there is something else.